# Alternating numbers

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, number-theory, formation-of-numbers

*Alternating numbers* are numbers in which all digits alternate between even and odd. For example: 2703 and 7230 are alternating numbers, but 2730 isn't.

Numbers are *very alternating* when double the number is an alternating number as well, for example 3816 is very alternating, because 7632 is an alternating number as well.

The question to you is: how many 4 digits very alternating numbers are there? (the number can't start with one or multiple zeros)

Of course this problem can be solved by programming, but it can be solved mathematically as well! Good luck!

NB: I didn't come up with this puzzle myself, it's part of the Dutch Math Olympiad, see [this PDF](http://www.wiskundeolympiade.nl/files/opgaven/1e-ronde/2015/opgaven_en.pdf)

Comment: in this scenario 5000 is the maximum of possible very alternating numbers, right?

Comment: the alternating number itself must be 4 digits, but the double of the alternating number may be more than that.

Comment: You may want to change your criteria to "...can't start with any number of zeroes", since the current wording could be interpreted to mean "[the number] one[, ] or multiple zeroes"

Comment: Does those number also count which are double are Alternating but greater than 10000 ?

Comment: Assuming we're sticking to 4-digits, it turns out there's only ONE very *very* alternating number: `1818`, which doubles to `3636`, and then again to `7272`.  There may be more if you allow the double and double-double to be 5 digits...

Comment: There *cannot* be a 4-digit very-alternating number whose double has 5 digits.  Proof: Every 5-digit number that is twice a 4-digit number *must* start with a 1, which is odd.  And all multiples of 2 must end in an even digit.  Since no odd-digit number that starts odd and ends even can possibly be alternating, there can be no very-alternating numbers between 5000 and 9999.

Comment: Just to add more neat observations, here's a complete list of very *very* alternating numbers below 10000: `3`, `9`, `18`, `109`, `309`, `418`, `818`, `909`, `1818`.  Of these, only `9`, `109`, and `909` are very *very* ***very*** alternating.  I'm pretty sure it's impossible to find one that's five levels of very alternating.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman You are right that the double mathematically can't be 5 digits, but it is *allowed* according to the rules, because I didn't want to give that hint away immediately

Comment: Oh wait, I'm wrong, there are technically three or possibly five (if you count negative) numbers with 5+ levels, but only on a trivial level: `2` is very (x4) alternating, `1` is very (x5) alternating, and `0` is infinitely alternating.  Also, the negative numbers mirror their positive counterparts, so `-2` and `-1` as well.  But larger numbers definitely can't go beyond 4 levels.  I could probably prove it, but it'd take more than a comment to do so.

Comment: There's a pattern for generating all very-very-alternating numbers up to infinity.  For an odd numbers of digits, start with `1`, `3`, and `9`, and append `09` repeated 0-N times, then start with `2`, `4`, and `8`, and append `18` repeated 0-N times.  For an even number of digits, it will always be `18` repeated 0-N times.  This should give you every possible very-very-alternating number.  (I also missed `4` and `8` in my first list - `4` is also a very (x3) alternating number.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There number of such numbers is

> 70

When you double a number, a digit of the result is even if and only if the digit to the right didn't carry.

Therefore, $2x$ is alternating if and only if the digits of $x$ are $LHLH$, where $L \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and $H \in \{5,6,7,8,9\}$.

(As a side note, this implies that if $x$ is very alternating, then $2x$ will still be a four digit number, so that $x < 5000$ necessarily).

We know that if $x$ is alternating when it looks like OEOE or EOEO. For $x$ to be very alternating, it also must be $LHLH$, so let's count the number of ways to fulfill both these constraints.

- **OEOE**: Each odd number must be low, meaning they are each $1$ or $3$. Each even must be high, so is either $6$ or $8$. There are two choices for each digit for a total of $2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2=16$ possibilities.
- **EOEO**: Now the evens are low ($0,2$ or $4$), and the odds are high ($5,7$ or $9$). There are three choices for each digit, except the first digit can't be zero, so there are $2\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3=54$ possibilities.

These two counts add to the desired answer.

Comment: I'm kind of lost on your explanation. I get to the LHLH but after that, maybe I'm dense?

Comment: According to the comments on the OP, the double of the alternating number can be more than 4 digits.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain It doesn't matter. A five-digit number has to start with 1, but its last digit must be even, so it can't alternate.

Comment: @f'' yeah, but also no 5 digit numbers make the cut anyway

Comment: @mikeearnest added a small bit to your answer.  Feel free to roll back if you don't like it

Comment: Yes, this is the right answer! Well done!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> 70

I did a manual count.  Still trying to work out a mathematical solution.

Comment: I'm sorry, that's not the answer. How did you come to this answer?

Comment: @xander check my latest edit

Comment: I'm sorry, still not the right answer

Comment: Wait, I see what I did wrong, hold on

Comment: @xander How about now?

Comment: Yes, you're right!

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is:

> 70

---

```
#AnubhavBalodhi, puzzling.stackexchange,26036, 1/2/16 2341 hrs
E=['0','2','4','6','8']
O=['1','3','5','7','9']

ans=0
alters=[]

def Alt(num):
N=str(num)
if len(N)<5: #4 digit
    if (N[0] in E and N[1] in O and N[2] in E and N[3] in O) or (N[0] in O and N[1] in E and N[2] in O and N[3] in E):
        alters.append(num)
else:       #5 digit
    if (N[0] in E and N[1] in O and N[2] in E and N[3] in O and N[4] in E ) or (N[0] in O and N[1] in E and N[2] in O and N[3] in E and N[4] in O):
        alters.append(num)

for num in range(1000,10**5):
Alt(num)
#print(num)

print(len(alters))

for numb in alters:
if numb<9999 and numb*2 in alters: #if the number in alternating list is of 4 digits, and its double is also in the list.
    print(numb)
    ans+=1
print("ans is %d" %(ans))
```

Answer (score 2):

Damn I started this <sup>brute force</sup> before the answers and I got

> 70

VBA

Better logic for this route would have been

```
if (one mod 2 = three mod 2) and (two mod 2 = four mod 2) then
    if one mod 2 <> two mod 2 then
     counter increase
```

Answer (score 2):

Here we go, brute force again!

The answer is, as pointed out in other answers:

> 70

You may check [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/moonlife/9jLh88hj/) for source code and full list of 4-digit very alternative numbers.